# How to submit Spark SQL application with parameter used in SQL statements?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to create a Scala file that has multiple SQL statements and each statement has few parameters. I'd like to execute/submit that file programmatically using shell file.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext;
val sqlContext = new HiveContext(sc);
val total=sqlContext.sql(s"select sum(amount) from table1 where location=$loc_var");
```

Answer (score 1):

just concatenate and construct the SQL but beware of single quotes in a string value!

Databricks example:

```
%python
string_value = "there is ' in the string"
string_value_escaped = string_value.replace("'", "''")

spark.sql(f"""
SELECT 
   '{string_value_escaped}' as a_string
""").display

spark.sql(f"""
SELECT 
   '{string_value}' as a_string
""").display()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [scopt](https://github.com/scopt/scopt) for command-line argument handling and use them in your Scala application, e.g. `loc_var`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you can append the input arguments using string concatenation.

```
//Capture input argument inside scala file
val loc_var = args(0)

val total=sqlContext.sql("select sum(amount) from table1 where location='"+loc_var+"'");
```

Comment: Thanks. I got it. It was helpful. I really appreciate your help